# return CPU usage from osutils node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a value into a variable from the `osutils` cpu usage method, but seem to be having some troubles in doing so.

```js
const osutils = require('os-utils')

function getCPUUsage () {
  const usage = osutils.cpuUsage((value) => {
    return value
  });

  return usage
}
```

I need to console.log the `getCPUUsage` function and expect it to contain a value

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Promises and wrapping the cpuUsage call like so:

```
const osutils = require('os-utils')

function getCPUUsage () {
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        osutils.cpuUsage(value => resolve(value))
    })
}

async function testCPUUsage() {
    const cpuUsage = await getCPUUsage();
    console.log(`test CPU usage: ${(cpuUsage * 100).toFixed(1)}%`);
}

testCPUUsage();
```